# Why can't make work my VHDL program using elsif not recognize one state

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I'am a spanish user an newbie on VHDL programming the problems its that I was trying to make a machine state with the CASE but don't work. then i decide to do with ELSIF instruction all its working perfect but the state 0010 its not working a I don't know why its a very ease program but don't understand why y is not working EXCUSE MY POOR ENGLISH but I do my best thanks I show the program next:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--definimos identidad de la interfaz
entity interfaz is 
port(
    sen:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);--entrada de sensor bus de 4 bits
    clk:in std_logic;
    mda, mdr, mia, mir:out std_logic);--mdr,mda=motor derecho retroceso,avance == mia,mir=motor izquiero avance,retroceso
end interfaz;
--comenzando arquitectura de interfaz
architecture behavior of interfaz is
----------------------------------------------------
--Instruccion con herramienta elseif
process
begin
wait until clk'event and clk='1';
if (sen=(0000)) then --alto
mda<='0'; 
mdr<='0'; 
mia<='0'; 
mir<='0';
elsif (sen=(0001)) then --retroceso
mda<='0';
mdr<='1';
mia<='0';
mir<='1';
elsif (sen=0010) then --avance
mda<='1';
mdr<='0';
mia<='1';
mir<='0';
elsif (sen=(0100)) then --izquierda
mda<='0';
mdr<='1';
mia<='1';
mir<='0';
elsif (sen=(1000)) then --derecha
mda<='1';
mdr<='0';
mia<='0';
mir<='1';
end if;

end process;
end behavior;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sen=0010` appears like `sen` is compared to a 4-bit vector, but it is
actually compare with the decimal value 0010 = 10 = ten, due to the lack of
`""` around the `0010` value.  Fix this in all place with by adding `""`, like
`"0010"`.

VHDL is basically strong typed, but the `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;` adds
functions that allows compare between `std_logic_vector` and `integer`, and for
this reason the problem passes syntax check.

Also:

- Fix a syntax error by adding `begin` before the `process`, since that is
  required in `architecture`
- Consider using if `rising_edge(clk)` instead of `wait until clk'event and clk='1'`
- Consider rewrite with `case`

Comment: Hi Morten thanks for the fast answer i going to check the fix and tell how was it goog luck friend

Comment: Hi again Morten thanks for the help i was able to fix my problem is working FINE i gonna try rewrite using case but for now its fine THANKS AND GOODLUCK